# Как вывести сообщение в РНР

Tags: php

В php файле (выводит тело сообщения на странице с контентом) хотел вывести IP

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

.....

$message = ' Информацию и ваш ip <? echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?> ';
```

- но в таком виде не работает. Пожалуйста подскажите как правильно прописывать код вызова ip! Спасибо.

Comment: Здесь неправильно **всё** кроме получения IP адреса.

Comment: **Сначала** водится заголовок, а любые сообщения выводятся уже после. Если мы хотим что-то вывести, то и надо выводить, а не присваивать переменной. РНР тег выглядит как `<?php`, а не `<?`.

Comment: Уберите точки, надеюсь в коде их нет.. `$message` это просто переменная, она не может выводить что-то (на самом деле может, но речь о вашем случае), вы записываете строку - добавляйте данные к строке `$message = 'Информация и ваш ip ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` и теперь можно будет вывести строку `echo $message;`